# search and return that line from string in php

Tags: php

I have a mail template like below (its stored into DB):

```
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Column1: {column1}</p>
<p>Column2: {column2}</p>
<p>Column3: {column3}</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
```

what i am doing is find column in that string and replace it.

Example code:

```
public function generate_template($old_value,$new_value)
{
    $this->changeble_params = array('column1'=>'column1','column2'=>'column2');
    foreach($this->changeble_params as $key=>$param)
    {
         if($old_value[$key]!=$new_value[$key])
         {
              //Highlight that <p> tag
         }
         else
         {
              $message = str_replace($key, 'actualValueFromDB', $message);
         }

    }
}
```

Now if old value of column is not matched then highlight that row. So suppose
column1's value was **xyz** and if it is now **abc**

Then i need to highlight that row means template should be like below:

```
<p>Hello,</p>
<p style="color:yellow">Column1: abc</p>
<p>Column2: value of column2</p>
<p>Column3: value of column3</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
*note: Please note style in <p> tag.
```

So how to achieve that?

Comment: `So suppose column1's value was xyz and if it is now abc`? from where you get new value (abc)?

Comment: I am passing old and new value to that function. So i am able to check that value is changed or not.

Comment: which function?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have modified the code, please check.

Comment: A little trick. Add class to all of them. call it class="default" 
if the condition returns true, then just replace that class name with the class you want or  CSS you want. If this helps, I will add a full answer. In other words, add a place holder and then replace it.

Comment: Is that HTML code at the beginning is treated as a string?

Comment: i think i miss something `changeble_params` is not associative array , how could you make this `foreach($this->changeble_params as $key=>$param)`

Comment: @Ali I couldn't understand his code as well. By the way, what does the code loop into?

Comment: @Joraid Yes that HTML code is available as string.

Comment: @Ali Sorry was missed that while adding code, its associate array.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got your question correctly.

If the HTML template is available as a string. You can add a place holder to reserve a spot for the styling. And when your condition applies. Replace that place holder with your style string.

```
<p data-placeholder >Hello,</p>
<p data-placeholder >Column1: {column1}</p>
<p data-placeholder >Column2: {column2}</p>
<p>Column3: {column3}</p>
 $style= "style='color:yellow'"
if($old_value[$key]!=$new_value[$key])
   {
     $message = str_replace("data-placeholder", 'actualValueFromDB', $style);
     }
    else
    {
     $message = str_replace($key, 'actualValueFromDB', $message);
    //to remvoe un-needed place-holders. We can use and array and just on str_replace line instead. 
     $message = str_replace("data-placeholder", 'actualValueFromDB', "");
    }
```

---

## Update

Given this input

```
$str = "<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Column1: {column1}</p>
<p>Column2: {column2}</p>
<p>Column3: {column3}</p>
<p>Thanks</p>";
```

Supplied array of search needle to see if any of the `<p>` elements contain the following:

```
$toFind = array('column1' => 'column1', 'column2' => 'column2');
```

Convert to array and remove the `<p>` Tag

```
$strArr = explode(("<p>"), $str);
print_r($strArr);
```

Result:

```
  Array
  (
  [0] =>
  [1] => Hello,</p>
  [2] => Column1: {column1}</p>
  [3] => Column2: {column2}</p>
  [4] => Column3: {column3}</p>
  [5] => Thanks</p>
  )
```

Restyle the `<p>`

```
$newStr = stylePar($strArr, $toFind);
print_r($newStr);
```

**Result**:

```
   <p style='red'>Hello,</p>
   <p>Column1: {column1}</p>
   <p>Column2: {column2}</p>
   <p style='red'>Column3: {column3}</p>
   <p style='red'>Thanks</p>
```

---

Takes two arrays in the argument. Loops through the first array, and for each cell, it will loop through the second array. If the value from the second array exists in the first array, style tag will be added. 
Returns string.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type Array: $hayStackArr
 * @param type Array: $needlsArr
 * @return type string
 */
function stylePar($hayStackArr, $needlsArr) {
    $styledTag = "<p style='red'>";
    $tag = "<p>";
    $found = false; // default

    foreach ($hayStackArr as $key => $val) {

        if (empty($hayStackArr[$key])) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($needlsArr as $searchKey => $searchTerm) {
            if (stripos($hayStackArr[$key], $needlsArr[$searchKey]) !== false) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            $hayStackArr[$key] = $styledTag . $hayStackArr[$key];
        } else {
            $hayStackArr[$key] = $tag . $hayStackArr[$key];
        }
        $found = false;
    }
    return implode("", $hayStackArr);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it replace all of the data-placeholder which is in string? What i want is just highlight that paricular <p> tag

Comment: Alright, I got what you mean. Editing code now. I will explode the string for each <p> in a separate index and then process that. For some reason, I thought the loop will loop through line by line.

Comment: @DS9 your loop, what does loop through? I mean, what is it for?

Comment: its checking that those params is available or not in string, if available then it will replace the value of that column.

Comment: Say, array has 2 column column1 and column2, so loop will iterate 2 times and find that in  html string. it will replace the value. like column1 with actual name.

Comment: thanks for your help, i am able to do that using your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MJoraid, i am able to do that using below:

I have added the **{style_columnname}** in < p > tag.

```
<p>Hello,</p>
<p style="{style_column1}">Column1: {column1}</p>
<p style="{style_column2}">Column2: {column2}</p>
<p>Column3: {column3}</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
```

After that i just need to find that **style_columnname** and just replace it.

```
public function generate_template($old_value,$new_value)
{
    $this->changeble_params = array('column1'=>'column1','column2'=>'column2');
    foreach($this->changeble_params as $key=>$param)
    {
         if($old_value[$key]!=$new_value[$key])
         {
              $message = str_replace("style_".$key, 'color:yellow', $message);
         }
         else
         {
              $message = str_replace($key, 'actualValueFromDB', $message);
         }

    }
}
```